# Convergence in sup norm of elementary integrals to the Itô integral process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion, and $X$ a continuous process adapted to $W$ such that $\int_0^T X^2 \, ds < \infty$ almost surely for some $T > 0$.

Define for any sequence of partitions $\mathcal P_n = \{t_1^n, \dotsc t_{k_n} ^n\}$ of $[0, T]$, the elementary integral process $Y^n$ associated to $\mathcal P_n$ by

$$Y_t^n := \sum_{i = 1}^{k_n - 1} X_{t^n_i} (W_{t^n_{i+i} \wedge t} - W_{t^n_{i} \wedge t} \,).$$

**Question:** Is it true that for all partitions $\mathcal P_n$ of $[0, T]$ with mesh going to $0$, we have

$$\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} \left\lvert\int_0^t X_s \, dW_s - Y_t^n\right\rvert \to 0$$

in probability?

Comment: is the concern the supremum? Because L2 convergence implies in probability.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056322/itos-integral-converge-in-probability

Comment: Yes, the usual result says that the term inside the sup converges to $0$ in probability, but I don’t see that it implies the sup converges to $0$ in probability.

Comment: i am thinking of using some variation of Doob's inequality. Do you think you can extract some martingale out of their difference?

Comment: Ohh, that’s a good idea. The term in the sup (without the absolute values) is a martingale no? Being the difference of two martingales.

Comment: Is $(X_s)$ appropriately adapted?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention. Will add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
\begin{equation*}
    X^{(n)}_t=\sum_{i=1}^{k_n-1} X_{t_i^n}1_{(t_i^n,t_{i+1}^n]}(t).
\end{equation*}
Since $X=\{X_t,0\le t\le T\}$ is a continuous adapted process, then
\begin{gather*}
    \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{0\le t\le T}|X^{(n)}_t - X_t |=0, \qquad \text{a.s.}, \\
    \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{T} (X^{(n)}_t - X_t )^2\,\mathrm{d}t=0, \qquad \text{a.s.},
\end{gather*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\Big(\Big|\int_{0}^{T} (X^{(n)}_t - X_t )^2\, \mathrm{d}t \Big| >d\Big)=0, \quad \forall d>0. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Due to $(\int_0^t (X^{n}_s-X_s)\mathrm{d}W_s)^2$ is L-dominated by
\begin{equation*}
   \langle \int_0^{\cdot} (X^{(n)}_s-X_s)\mathrm{d}W_s \rangle_t =
   \int_{0}^{t} (X^{(n)}_s - X_s )^2\,\mathrm{d}s.
\end{equation*}
Using Lenglart's inequality(cf.   S. W. He *et al., Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus*, Sci. Press and CRC(1992). **Th**9.26, pp240, or
J. Jacod, and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003, **Lemma** I.3.30, pp35.), we get
\begin{align*}
    &\mathsf{P}\Big(\sup_{0\le t\le T}\Big[\int_0^t (X^{(n)}_s-X_s) \mathrm{d}W_s \Big]^2 \ge\epsilon  \Big)\\
 &\quad\le \frac{d}{\epsilon}+\mathsf{P}\Big[\int_{0}^{T} (X^{(n)}_t - X_t )^2\,\mathrm{d}t \ge d\Big].  \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Now, by (1), letting $n\to\infty$ and $d\downarrow 0$ consecutively in (2),
we obtain immediately the following assertion,
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\Big(\sup_{0\le t\le T}\Big|\int_0^t (X^{(n)}_s-X_s) \mathrm{d}W_s \Big|\ge\epsilon  \Big)=0, \qquad \forall \epsilon>0. 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The difference of two martingales is still a martingale by linearity of conditional expectation and so

$$Z^n_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t}X_{s}dW_{s}-\sum_{i = 1}^{k_n - 1} X_{t^n_i} (W_{t^n_{i+i} \wedge t} - W_{t^n_{i} \wedge t} \,)$$

is a martingale for each $n$. Indeed, the first term is a martingale by the properties of stochastic integration, while the latter is a martingale transform of a martingale.

Thus we can apply Doob's inequality for $p=2$:

$$\text{E}[| Z^n_T |^p] \leq \text{E}\left[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T} |Z^n_s|^p\right] \leq \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p\text{E}[|Z^n_T|^p]$$

to get $L^{2}$-convergence of the supremum as well. For probability-convergence we can use the weaker version

$$\text{P}[\sup_t|Z_t^{n}|\geq C]\leq \frac{\text{E}[|Z_T^{n}|^p]}{C^p}.$$

In terms of the $L_{2}$ convergence one needs a bit more structure. There are many references eg. see [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eagazzi/notesSDEv1.03.pdf) Theorem 5.3.

[image]

Now we verify the assumption for the L2 convergence of the elementary processes

$$\phi_{n}(t):=\sum_{i = 1}^{k_n - 1} X_{t^n_i} 1_{[t^n_i,t^n_{i+1}]}$$

to $X_{t}$. For reference of the last one, also see Oksendal SDEs on pags 26-28. When $X_{t}$ is bounded one can use the above simple-functions.

[image]

and when $X_{t}$ is unbounded, one can use the following approximation from his step 3

$$\psi_{n}(t):=1_{X_{t}\in [-n,n]}\sum_{i = 1}^{k_n - 1} X_{t^n_i} 1_{[t^n_i,t^n_{i+1}]}-n1_{X_{t}\leq -n}+n1_{X_{t}\geq n}.$$

So if one wants to just have $\phi_{n}$ as the approximation, they would need the following terms to go to zero

$$\int_{0}^{T} E[|\phi_{n}(t)-n|^{2}1_{X(t)>n}]+E[|\phi_{n}(t)+n|^{2}1_{X(t)<-n}]dt.$$

I will try to check if this can be obtained given the above particular assumptions on $X$ or whether there are counterexamples. Other answers are welcome.

Comment: Wait, I think there is a problem. How do we know that $Z^n_t \to 0$ in $L^2$? The usual result only says we have convergence in probability.

Comment: Hm, I don’t see a proof of $L^2$ convergence there… it is claimed in the linked post but I believe the claim is false - the usual $L^2$ construction of elementary integrals does not use $X_{t^n_i}$ as the elementary integrands.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. However, the hypotheses of Theorem 5.3, namely that the elementary processes converge in $L^2$, has not been verified in our case.

Comment: Thanks again. But I think there is still a problem - Lemma 5.1 and Theorem 5.2 say that there exists a sequence of elementary processes approximating $X$, however nowhere is it said that these processes are given by our particular choice of elementary integrands.

Comment: Sorry, that is not immediate to me - the $\phi_n (t)$ converge to $X$ only pointwise almost surely. I don’t see how to obtain $L^2$ convergence. Please check carefully again if it is immediate.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by your last comment.

Comment: This is the Riemann Stiltjes integral, not the stochastic integral… I’m sorry since we cannot come to an agreement I suggest we stop this discussion. Meanwhile I will leave the question and answer open for others to contribute.

Comment: Yes, the sup goes to $0$ almost surely but this still does not imply $L^2 (\Omega \times [0, T])$ convergence. Sorry, I’m just done here.

Comment: “For all $n$ large enough, $|\phi_n (t)| \leq |X_t| + 1$.” This does not happen uniformly in $\omega$, so the dominated convergence theorem cannot be applied. Further the reference by Oksendal assumes $g$ to be bounded.

Comment: Updated answer. I agree with you; it is tricker than it looks. So Oksendal has a slightly different approximation that also includes the unbounded case.

Comment: In terms of using the approximation you wrote with $\phi_n$, my guess is that a counterexample should work at least in the $L^{2}$-case of a process $X_{t}>n$ that satisfies $P[X_{t}>n]$=1/n$ so that the above terms will diverge. It would be interesting if it still works in probability.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the effort so far! It has helped me to see that under stronger conditions (eg $X$ bounded) we can indeed get the result.